# How can I match exact 5 characters with additional conditional?

Tags: regex

I need to match a group of exact 5 characters 1's. Example below

```
02011111020 // match
00211111200 // Not match because there are 2 at start and end of group
00111111100 // Not match because there are 6 1's
```

So far, I have try with pattern

- `(?!2)(1{5}?)(?!2)` but fail at `00111111100`
- `\D(1{5}?)\D` but fail at `02011111020`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition `(?!2)` is always true as the next character to match is a 1 and this condition `(?!2)` asserts not a 2, which will be true if there is still a 1 to the right.

This `\D` means matching a character other than a digit, which can never match in a string with only digits.

You can exclude matching 1 and 2 using a character class `[12]` and lookarounds:

```
(?<![12])1{5}(?![12])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<![12])` Negative lookbehind, assert not 1 or 2 to the left
- `1{5}` match 5 times a 1
- `(?![12])` Negative lookahead, assert not 1 or 2 to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MtUdXb/1)

Comment: Very good use of lookarounds!

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74490831/10819573) uses the lookarounds nicely. Using the same technique, given below is a simpler solution to your problem:

```
(?<=0)1{5}(?=0)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=0)` Positive lookbehind, assert 0 to the left
- `1{5}` match 5 times a 1
- `(?=0)` Positive lookahead, assert 0 to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5zsO0A/1)

Comment: I was thinking about that, but there is a `(?!2)` in the question, and in that case  I thought 5 times a 1 like `11111` should also match. Still ++ because it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Matching a line with 5 consecutive `1`s that are preceded and followed by a `0`:

```
.*01{5}0.*
```